# Unable to call Graphql API using input parameters

Tags: ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

I'm able to call a graphql api by passing in the input directy like this

```
mutation {
  createUser(input: {
    email: "user+2@example.com",
    password: "Password123!",
    passwordconfirmation: "Password123!",
    firstName: "Richard",
    lastName: "James"
  }){
    user{
      firstName
      lastName
      email
    }
  }
}
```

But if I pass it using input params like this

```
mutation createUser($input: CreateUserInput!) {
  createUser(input: $input){
    user{
      firstName
      lastName
      email
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable $input of type CreateUserInput! was provided invalid value for first_name (Field is not defined on CreateUserInput), last_name (Field is not defined on CreateUserInput)",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 21
        }
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "value": {
          "passwordconfirmation": "Password123!",
          "password": "Password123!",
          "email": "user@example.com",
          "first_name": "Richard",
          "last_name": "James"
        },
        "problems": [
          {
            "path": [
              "first_name"
            ],
            "explanation": "Field is not defined on CreateUserInput"
          },
          {
            "path": [
              "last_name"
            ],
            "explanation": "Field is not defined on CreateUserInput"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

***create user mutation***

```
module Mutations
  class CreateUser < Mutations::BaseMutation
    argument :email, String, required: true
    argument :password, String, required: true
    argument :passwordconfirmation, String, required: true
    argument :first_name, String, required: false
    argument :last_name, String, required: false

    field :user, Types::UserType, null: true
    field :token, String, null: true

    def resolve(args)
      user = User.new(password: args[:password], password_confirmation: args[:passwordconfirmation], email: args[:email])
      user.build_profile
      user.save
      if args[:first_name] || args[:last_name]
        user.profile.first_name = args[:first_name]
        user.profile.last_name = args[:last_name]
        user.profile.save
      end

      # current_user needs to be set so authenticationToken can be returned
      context[:current_user] = user

      MutationResult.call(
        obj: { user: user },
        success: user.persisted?,
        errors: user.errors
      )
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
      GraphQL::ExecutionError.new(
        "Invalid Attributes for #{e.record.class.name}: " \
        "#{e.record.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}"
      )
    end
  end
end
```

***CreateUserInput***

```
input: CreateUserInput!
Autogenerated input type of CreateUser

type CreateUserInput {
  email: String!
  password: String!
  passwordconfirmation: String!
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  clientMutationId: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message already tells you what's up :)

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable $input of type CreateUserInput! was provided invalid value for first_name (Field is not defined on CreateUserInput), last_name (Field is not defined on CreateUserInput)",**
    }
    ...
```

That means, that your `CreateUserInput` type doesn't match your payload. You haven't posted your `CreateUserInput`, but it appears that it contains neither `first_name` nor `last_name`. I assume `CreateUserInput` looks something like this:

```rb
class CreateUserInput < BaseInput 
  argument :email, String, required: true
  argument :password, String, required: true
  argument :password_confirmation, String, required: true, camelize: true
  argument :first_name, String, required: false, camelize: true
  argument :last_name, String, required: false, camelize: true
end
```

Note that `camelize: true` is set per default, and results in fields like `firstName` and `lastName`. So your input varible must now look like so:

```json
input: {
  "firstName": "First",
  "lastName": "Last",
  ...
}
```

If you wish to stick with `first_name` you must pass `camelize: false` and change your payload accordingly.

Inspect your GraphQL API using a documentation explorer to see what kind of fields your API expects and how they should be named.

Comment: I'm not passing it as `first_name` but as `firstName` which is in the autogenerated `CreateUserInput`. I will post above

Comment: @AntarrByrd The error message you posted clearly says that you send `first_name` and `last_name` instead of `firstName` and `lastName`. See the value field...

Comment: I understand this, but I am not.